# Unexpected behaviour when creating dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
word = 'pythonist'

#splitting word into its alphabets
newword = []
for char in word:
    newword.append(char)

print newword

##########################

#creating the dict

d = {}
length = len(word)


for x in range(0,length):
    d["{0}".format(x)] = newword[x]

print d
```

If you notice the dictionary key:value is not in the same order the letters in the string 'pythonist'.  What is causing this behaviour? Im thinking, it's something to do with the way the dictionary is created because im letting the values for the dict be taken from a list I just created?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered. If want to maintain order you should be using an `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Tip - You could replace ```"{0}".format(x)``` with ```str(x)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be simplified quite a bit:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

word = 'pythonist'

d = OrderedDict()
for x, c in enumerate(word):
    d["{0}".format(x)] = c

print d
```

This code produces the output:

```
OrderedDict([('0', 'p'), ('1', 'y'), ('2', 't'), ('3', 'h'), ('4', 'o'), ('5', 'n'), ('6', 'i'), ('7', 's'), ('8', 't')])
```

As you can see, courtesy of `OrderedDict`, the output is in order.

#### Notes

- There is no need to split `word` into `newword`.  In python, strings are themselves iterables.
- In computer programming, the need for constructions like this appears often:

  ```
  for x in range(0,length):
      d["{0}".format(x)] = newword[x]
  ```

  For this reason, python created `enumerate` which gives you both `x`, and `newword[x]` at the same time.
- The documentation for `OrderedDict` is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).  For reasons of speed, conventional python dictionaries are unordered.  When this is not satisfactory, use the class `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Thanks for the enumerate tip John!  I'm splitting word into newword because the problem im trying to solve eventually requires(atleast I think it does) a rearrangement of letters.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries in python are implemented as HashTables which are unordered containers.  `OrderedDict` will retain the order.

You can read about `OrderedDict` here:
[OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 0):

Python's dictionaries are unsorted as a design decision. Your dictionary is created correctly it is only that the information about order is lost.